# AVplayer playImmediatelyAtRate equivalent for IOS 9 and below

Tags: ios, avplayer, ios10, buffering, avplayeritem

I'am doing a project which includes playing sound from URL ,
everything's working perfect except of the start delay for the player .
Iam using AVplayer and by observing the `loadedTimeRanges` proberty of the `AVPlayerItem` and I realized that it buffers more than enough , so I needed to reduce that buffer size so the playback could start before .
I have read a lot and found out that Apple resolved this by introducing  the `playImmediatelyAtRate` function , which is available only in IOS >=10 versions.
my question is : how can I implement that in IOS <10 versions ? can I force the player to play after a particular buffer size ? any other ways ?